# Setting the theme to prevent actionbar

Tags: android

In Android Studio, when I open up an activity in the designer window and then set the theme to NoActionBar and then run my app, the actionbar is still visible. Is setting this in the design window only meant to give you a preview of what it would look like? Normally I set the theme inside the manifest and this works. But I am wondering why it doesn't work when set from the designer window.

Comment: Yes. you need to set NoActionBar in styles.xml. To view UI without Toolbar

Comment: @Venky Why set it in styles.xml when I can just set it in the manifest? I was kind of assuming that setting it in the designer would not only give me a preview but set it during runtime - but it does not appear to do that.

Comment: post the manifest file code.

Comment: @AndroidDev You are right but it will only for that single activity. But this line android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" play an important role in the application tag of the manifest.